# Why do passive transformations must have continuous second partial derivatives?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, analytic-geometry

Here, by passive transformation, I mean the transformation of the coordinate system.

While watching the following video on YouTube on coordinate transformation,

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtpVVcKXfnA&list=PLdgVBOaXkb9D6zw47gsrtE5XqLeRPh27),

the author mentioned three conditions for a set of transformation equations to satisfy in order to be a coordinate transformation.
1. All functions must be real valued.
2. All functions must have continuous second partial derivatives.
3. All functions must be invertible.

I do intuitively understand the conditions 1 and 3. But regarding the second condition, I don't understand the reason.

[image]

To summarize my question,
If, $\overline{x_i}=f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)$ where the integral index $i$ varies from $1$ to $n$, be a set of $n$ transformation equations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ space to $\mathbb{R}^n$ space, with $f_i$ being bijective functions, how do we determine if the transformation is a coordinate transformation and not an active transformation (one that changes the shape of an object defined in a specific coordinate system)?

Well, the reference video says that the functions $f_i$ must have continuous second partial derivatives. That must count in all the second partial derivatives (mixed and unmixed), in which case, Clairaut's theorem will hold. Thus, at any point in the coordinate system, 
$f_{{x_i}{x_j}}=f_{{x_j}{x_i}}$.
How does that determine if the transformation is a passive and not an active one?

Comment: In some applications in differential geometry, you in fact want continuous third-order partial derivatives. You're not giving context to your question. What is the setting in which we're studying this?

Comment: By the way, I have no idea what "passive" transformations are. And the linear algebra and linear transformation tags do not apply, as this is all in the setting of multivariable calculus.

Comment: @TedShifrin, removed the tags which were redundant as indicated by you. I have added more elaboration to explain my question better.